# Remote access to OrientDB embedded server

Tags: java, orientdb, embedded-database

*using Community Edition v2.1.11*

I write a simple data synchronizer, that gets the data from MS-SQL DB, and synchronizes it with data that I have in OrientDB graph.

Updates may be rather massive, and the graph should be updated every 20 minutes, so I'd prefer to use the plocal mode for it; also, other applications should have all-time read access to the graph, so I decided to embed the server inside the Java app, and put the synchronization process to the scheduler (ScheduledExecutorService).

The problem is, that despite the [docs](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Embedded-Server.html), I can't access the DB that runs on the embedded server from the console or studio:

> orientdb> connect remote:localhost/test root myP@ss
>
> Disconnecting from the database [null]...OK Connecting to database
>   [remote:localhost/test] with user 'root'... Error:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot
>   open local storage 'C:/orientdb/databases/test' with mode=rw
>
> Error:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException:
>   Cann ot load database's configuration. The database seems corrupted
>
> Error: com.orientechnologies.common.concur.lock.OLockException: File
>   'C:\orientd b\databases\test\database.ocf' is locked by another
>   process, maybe the database is in use by another process. Use the
>   remote mode with a OrientDB server to allo w multiple access to the
>   same database

Here's my server initialization code:

```
String orientdbHome = "C:/orientdb/";
System.setProperty("ORIENTDB_HOME", orientdbHome);
OServer server = OServerMain.create();
server.startup(new File("C:/orientdb/config/embedded_config.xml"));
OGlobalConfiguration.WAL_LOCATION.setValue("/Temp/wal");
server.activate();

OrientGraph g = new OrientGraph("plocal:C:/orientdb/databases/Test");
```

I'm new to Orient, so I'm sure that I miss something, but even Google can't help me figuring out what exactly :(

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that when you connect using plocal protocol it locks the resources.

So you can't connect via console (even remote or plocal) after you've already created a plocal connection via `OrientGraph g = new OrientGraph("plocal:C:/orientdb/databases/Test");`

Comment: That's right, I know that it's impossible to connect to the graph in any way, while some other instance is connected to it by plocal; although when you read the docs, you can see this: "Java application that runs embedded with the server can bypass the remote connection and use the database directly with local mode. local and remote connections against the same database can work in concurrency: OrientDB will synchronize the access." Is it a deprecated feature or something? Local access is deprecated as I know - embedded server won't work that way with the new plocal storage?